# Can't get full post title if there a spaces in title

Tags: posts, php, query, links, get-the-title

I want to make a custom query that checks the post title and puts in a different URL like this:

```
<a href=bing.com/search?q=<?php echo single_post_title(); ?>>Blablabla</a>
```

But it does not work for me if I have a post with a space in it, like `Hello World`. Then it only shows me `Hello` in the link. How can I get the full post title?

I tried this too, but did not work, just like the first one.

```
<?php
$titletest = get_the_title();

echo " <a href=http://www.bing.com/search?q=$titletest>$titletest</a> ";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Damn, I came with a solution after I posted it....

```
echo ' <a href="http://www.bing.com/search?q=' . urlencode($titletest) . '">' . $titletest . '</a>';
```

Comment: +1 for solving your own question. Yes, spaces are invalid characters in URLs. You _have to_ encode them.